# iOS >> Device Orientation > Using the Same VC with Different UI

Tags: ios, device-orientation

I wish to create an app that supports both Portrait and Landscape presentation.

There is no difference between the UI objects when rotating - they remain the same and function the same way in both states.

The only thing that should change is where each UI object is located on screen:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

I assume that using Autolayout and Constraint won't work here since the objects actually change their location.

I wish to work in the same VC (.h and .m files), and if possible, design the screens UI in Storyboard - if it's not possible, than design one of them as a .xib file is cool as well.

The most important thing is: **How to write the code that supports that?**

Comment: The Stanford university iOS lectures (available via iTunes) have a good lecture on device orientation. Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

One way, is to set the new position and dimensions on rotating your view programatically.

You can use these functions:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self yourNewPositioningFunction:[self interfaceOrientation]];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self yourNewPositioningFunction:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```